# How to see IP info of connected client on an OpenSSH server running on Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

Is there any command for Windows server side which displays the info used to connect to the server via SSH? (ip, port, etc...)

Comment: Have you checked what you find in `/var/log/auth.log`?

Comment: the server runs on windows

Comment: Ah. This info should've been in your question. Please see [question guidelines](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help). As a new user it's a good idea to check the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour), Asking and Answering in the Help Center and some older questions with [accepted answers](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) to learn how SE sites differ from discussion forums. If there's new info to add or you're asked to clarify something, please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1778307/edit) the question instead of commenting.